# Do DD4T 2 and/or DXA 1.2 support java servlet 2.5 instead of servlet 3.0

Tags: dd4t, dxa

The current version of DD4T (ver 2.0.3) uses a lot of java servlet 3.0 features including dispatcher type, etc. However our deployment environment is WebLogic 11g, which uses the servlet 2.5. This is also true for DXA. We want to use DD4T 2 or DXA with its JSON support. Instead of modifying the source code, is there any other implementation of DD4T 2 that can support java servlet 2.5?

Answer (score 3):

Good question. I tried to compile DD4T 2 against servlet-api 2.5 and indeed it only breaks on org.dd4t.core.util.HttpUtils.java. Since I know of no forks of dd4t-2-java which do this, I think you'll have to redo that code to make it work on WebLogic 11g, which should not be that much work.

Comment: Thank you Raimond for the answer, however, this class is currently used by several other classes, from you experience are there any side effects by re-implement this class? Thanks.

Comment: No, not really - as long as the methods keep doing what they're doing now. :) I'll see if I have time to look into it as well, as I'd like dd4t to be as versionless as possible.